# Keeping controllers in different files not working in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am currently defining my global module in my `routes.js`, but for some reason the other controllers are not being created and I keep getting errors that say that my main app module 'LiveAPP' is not available. Here is my code:

**routes.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP', ['ngRoute'])

.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/home.html',
    controller  : 'mainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signup',{
    templateUrl : '/signup.html',
    controller  : 'signUpCtrl'
  })
  .when('/artist',{
    templateUrl : '/artistpage.html',
    controller  : 'artistCtrl'
  })
})
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP')
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location',mainCtrl]);

function mainCtrl($scope,$http,$location){
  $scope.somefunc = function(artistname){
    dataFactory.ArtistfromSpotify()
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      console.log(data)
    })

  }
};
```

**signUpCtrl**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP')
.controller('signUpCtrl', ['$scope','$http',signUpCtrl]);

function signUpCtrl($scope,$http){
  $scope.user = {
    email:'',
    password:''
  }

  $scope.postreq = function(user){
    $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "/signup",
          data:{
            user_username:user.email,
            user_password:user.password
          }      
      }).success(function(data){

        console.log("User posted to the database")
      });
};
}
```

**artistCtrl**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP')
.controller('artistCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.myRating = 
  {number:3}
}])
.directive("rateYo", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            rating: "="
        },
        template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
        link: function( scope, ele, attrs ) {
            console.log(scope.rating.number)
            $(ele).rateYo({
                rating: scope.rating.number
            });
        }
    };
});
```

I was under the impression that I could retrieve the main liveAPP module and add controllers in other files by using `angular.model('liveAPP').controller(...)` For some reason it's not working. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: You need to change your signUpCtrl to

Comment: are you loading `routes.js` before any of the controller files?

Comment: This is why I always advocate one module per file. You can load the files in any order and not run into these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment above, when you re-use the same module across files, you need to load the files in the right order to satisfy dependencies as well as ensure the module is created before being used.

An easy way to avoid this problem is to specify one module per file. For example

`mainCtrl.js`

```
(function() {
    angular.module('LiveAPP.main', [])

        .controller('mainCtrl', ...);
})();
```

---

and in your `routes.js`

```
(function() {
    angular.module('LiveAPP', [
        'ngRoute',
        'LiveAPP.main'
    ])

        .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })...
        });
})();
```

Comment: So is it a best practice to define new modules for each controller? That's what I had initially and then just injected all them into routes.js, but then I wanted to create a factory in routes.js and I wanted to be able to use the functions from this factory in the controller modules and ran into trouble there too. Should I create new file for a factory? If so, how would I go about making sure that I could use these functions in the various controllers? Would that just be like this `angular.module('LiveAPP.main', ['factory'])`?

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it *best practice* but it's certainly how the *angular-seed* project is structured. I would say define new modules for each file at least. It's probably neater to only do one thing in each file but that's up to you. And yes, you would simply include the module with whatever you need in it in the list of dependencies wherever required.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your html file is including the js files in the wrong order. You need to make sure that routes.js appears first in the html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change signUpCtrl.js to

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.controller', [])
.controller('signUpCtrl', ['$scope','$http',signUpCtrl]);
```

and inject **LiveAPP.controller** to your global module

```
angular.module('LiveAPP', ['ngRoute', 'LiveAPP.controller'])
```

You cannot have **LiveAPP** in more than one module. Make the same updates on all of your controllers and inject that module names in routes.js

Comment: That's incorrect. `angular.module(moduleName)` is the **getter**. Passing a second array argument of dependencies makes it the **setter**.