# Very strange angular template render issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-components

I have the following code in index.html.

```
......
<my-test-app></my-test-app>

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-component-router/angular_1_router.js"></script>
<!--<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>-->
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="my-test/module.js"></script>
<script src="my-test/my-test-app.component.js"></script>
<script src="my-test/static/dashboard.component.js"></script>

<script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
```

In the my-test-app.component.js.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var module = angular.module("myTest");
    module.component("myTestApp", {
        templateUrl: "/my-test/my-test-app.component.html",
        $routeConfig: [
            { path: "/dashboard", component: "dashboard", name: "StaticDashboard" },
            { path: "/**", redirectTo: ["StaticDashboard", ""] }
        ]
    });
})();
```

and in my-test-app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse container-fluid">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">China deal</a></div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a ng-click="['StaticDashBoard']">Static - Dashboard</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <ng-outlet></ng-outlet>
</div>
```

my-test/static/dashboard.component.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var module = angular.module("myTest");
    module.component("dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "/my-test/static/dashboard.component.html",
    });
})();
```

And /my-test/static/dashboard.component.html has just one line

```
Test.....
```

Now I added a new file service.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myTest', ['ngResource'])
.factory('DashboardService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:5000/api/Dashboard/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
}]);
```

Everything works fine so far, I can see the text "Test..." displayed under the menu. However, the display of "Test..." is gone after I add `<script src="service.js"></script>` in the main index.html page as following.

```
<script src="my-test/module.js"></script>
<script src="service.js"></script>
<script src="my-test/my-test-app.component.js"></script>
<script src="my-test/static/dashboard.component.js"></script>
```

The Chrome javascript console didn't show any error message. The "Network" tab shows the file "/my-test/static/dashboard.component.html" was not even requested. And if I move the `<script src="service.js"></script>` two lines down as following. The whole page is blank?

```
<script src="my-test/module.js"></script>
<script src="my-test/my-test-app.component.js"></script>
<script src="my-test/static/dashboard.component.js"></script>
<script src="service.js"></script>
```

**Update:**

The module.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var module = angular.module("myTest", ["ngComponentRouter"]); // tried to put StaticDataService here but got error. 
    module.value("$routerRootComponent", "myTestApp");
})();
```

my-test/static/dashboard.component.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var module = angular.module("myTest");
    module.component("dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "/my-test/static/dashboard.component.html",
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: ['DashboardService', controller]
    });
})();
```

Error:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- DashboardService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20DashboardService
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4511
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4664)
    at angular.js:4516
    at getService (angular.js:4664)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4688)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4710)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4557)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4718)
    at angular.js:4517
```

Comment: Did you mean `dashboard.component.html` has "Test....."?

Comment: You're redefining your `myTest` module with this line ~ `angular.module('myTest', ['ngResource'])` in `servcice.js`

Comment: Right, I corrected the question.

Answer (score 3):

You are recreating the module in your service.js file with this line

`angular.module('myTest', ['ngResource'])`

adding the 2nd parameter creates the module, if you want to just get the module use the getting like this

`angular.module('myTest')`

And move the dependency `ngResource` to the `module.js` file where you create the module

**Update** i think the reason the page goes blank is because you place the service.js last and then it recreates the module after you created your components

Comment: so `angular.module('myTest', ['ngResource'])` will recreate the module but `angular.module('myTest')` will not?

Comment: yes, if you dont add the second parameter it just gets the module, `angular.module('myTest')` is a getter

Comment: My first version is `angular.module('myTest').factory(....` but it got error of cannot find ngResource so I added the second parameter. Now I assign it first `var module = angular.module("chinaDeal"); module.factory(....` and it seems work now. Still strange.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 This is why I like [one-module-per-file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30365119/283366). No issues with loading order and no accidental module overwrites

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 well you still need to add the `ngResource` dependency to the original myTest module,

Comment: @Phil It seems not possible to combine all the component (v1.5.8) js files code into one?

Comment: @WalksAway I did at the beginning but it still got the error. Maybe the page was not refreshed...

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 it still shows that `ngResource` wasn't loaded? you wanna post the angular error message + module.js code? if you inject the dependency to the module it should all work fine

Comment: Right, I actually got the error again. `angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- DashboardService`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 please post the module.js code and the error message

Comment: it cannot find the `$resource` service probably because the dependency isnt injected into the module you are assigning the service to

Comment: @WalksAway Posted.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 just like i said you are missing the `ngResource` injection add this:  `var module = angular.module("chinaDeal", ["ngComponentRouter", "ngResource"]);` to your module.js file,

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 wait these are different modules.... ? where are you creating the "myTest" module? you need to inject `ngResource` to that module something like : `angular.module("myTest", ["ngResource"]);` the reason you are getting that error is that `ngResource` isn't injected to the "myTest" module

Comment: @WalksAway There are the same module. I copied the wrong file. corrected.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 again you are still missing the ngResource injection `angular.module("myTest", ["ngComponentRouter", "ngResource"]);`

Comment: Correct. The error is gone after I added it. I got another error `angular.js:13920 TypeError: DashboardService.query(...).then is not a function`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 that is a completely different issue XD, from what i can see you don't have a query function in your `DashboardService`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 never mind i  guess that `$resource(...)` should have a query function, just debug the results and check it...

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 if it says `.then` is not a function then `DashboardService.query(...)` isn't returning a promise